# HttpContext.Current.Session null with DependencyInjectionProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I'm using DependencyInjectionProvider, and when I check the container I get a null session reference. Could someone tell me how to solve it? My code is as follows:

Code 1:

```
private Container Init()
    {
        var container = new Container();
        container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();
        container.Register<ConnectionString>(() => UserContext.Current?.connectionString ?? new ConnectionString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["banco_cliente"]), ScopedLifestyle.Scoped);
        SimpleInjectorContainer.RegisterMvc(container);
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
        container.Verify();
        return container;
    }
```

Code 2 (attribute Current of UserContext):

```
public static Current Current
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.Session["__contexto_do_usuario_logado__"] == null)
                    Inicializar();
                return HttpContext.Current.Session["__contexto_do_usuario_logado__"] as Current;
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand how the code in the first code block has any relationship to the second code block. Where is `Init()` getting called? What dependency injection framework are you using?

Comment: Init () is the method which calls the attribute that gives problem. I think the plugin calls SimpleInjector. I'm new to C # and this is a project from the company I'm currently working on

Comment: Is `Init` called within the context of a user request? If not, why would there be an HttpContext? And if it is...then why are you creating a container any time except app startup?

Comment: Have you added the UseSession middleware? May be unrelated but give it ago

Comment: Where would I put the Middleware code? I'm new to ASP.NET and this is a project that I recently joined

Answer (score 1):

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
//I'd put this toward the end of the code block but before your routing.
app.UseSession();
}
```

I don't believe sessions are enabled by default. By adding this line, makes session usable. I could be wrong.

Comment: shoud this file must be at Startup.cs?

Comment: I've assumed without checking... This solution is for aspnet.net core projects. Inside your startup.cs you'll have the configure method, just have to add the line